# Random keyboard input on shutdown will power up Macbook Pro

Tags: macbook-pro, keyboard, shutdown

I am using a 2018 15" Macbook Pro (MR932). It is the base model for the 15". My mac is on Mojave (OS X 10.14).

After I shut down my mac, any random key input will switch my mac back on. I have tried resetting my SMC and the problem still occur. Is it related to software or hardware? It is quite annoying since that sometimes I need to shut down my mac to clean my keyboard. Is there any solution to it?

```
Assertion status system-wide:
   BackgroundTask                 1
   ApplePushServiceTask           0
   UserIsActive                   1
   PreventUserIdleDisplaySleep    0
   PreventSystemSleep             0
   ExternalMedia                  0
   InternalPreventDisplaySleep    1
   PreventUserIdleSystemSleep     1
   NetworkClientActive            0
Listed by owning process:
   pid 208(mds_stores): [0x0000cfd0000b9a16] 00:00:00 BackgroundTask named: "com.apple.metadata.mds_stores.power"
   pid 178(coreaudiod): [0x0000cc0c00019977] 00:16:04 PreventUserIdleSystemSleep named: "com.apple.audio.BuiltInHeadphoneOutputDevice.context.preventuseridlesleep"
    Created for PID: 384.
   pid 100(hidd): [0x0000c85b00099855] 00:00:00 UserIsActive named: "com.apple.iohideventsystem.queue.tickle.4295221011.3"
    Timeout will fire in 300 secs Action=TimeoutActionRelease
   pid 6959(Folx): [0x0000cccb000199de] 00:12:53 PreventUserIdleSystemSleep named: "PreventUserIdleSystemSleep"
   pid 254(UserEventAgent): [0x0000cce4000b99e5] 00:12:28 BackgroundTask named: "com.apple.AddressBook.ScheduledSync"
    Created for PID: 12084.
   pid 12084(AddressBookSourceSync): [0x0000cce4000199e4] 00:12:28 PreventUserIdleSystemSleep named: "Address Book Source Sync"
    Timeout will fire in 1051 secs Action=TimeoutActionTurnOff
   pid 56(powerd): [0x0000cc19001082f6] 00:02:31 InternalPreventDisplaySleep named: "com.apple.powermanagement.delayDisplayOff"
    Timeout will fire in 148 secs Action=TimeoutActionTurnOff
No kernel assertions.
Idle sleep preventers: IODisplayWrangler
```

**UPDATE**

Apple have reply to my Bug Report and it happened to be a feature instead of a bug.

> This issue behaves as intended based on the following:
>
> This a new feature with laptops where lid open and key presses cause
>   system to boot.
>
> It is called boot on any key press feature.
>
> We are now closing this bug report.
>
> If you have questions about the resolution, or if this is still a
>   critical issue for you, then please update your bug report with that
>   information.

Comment: so it was not shut down, just in deep sleep

Comment: @Buscar웃 well, I press the shutdown option though. How am I supposed to get a shutdown then if I get a "deep sleep" even I already pressed the shutdown? It sounds so unreal.

Comment: lets try to find out, use `pmset -g assertions`  in terminal to see if someone is keeping it awake.

Comment: @Buscar웃 okay, I have edited my post with the result. Mind to take a look?

Comment: Press the power button to turn on the Mac or wake from sleep.
    ...Press and hold the power button for 5 seconds without lifting to force your Mac to turn off.
    ...Press and hold power button for 1.5 seconds to get the turn off dialog. This dialog will ask if you want to restart, shutdown or put the Mac to sleep.

Comment: @Buscar웃 so this is the step (CMIIW):
1. Shutdown my mac
2. Press the power button to turn it on and release it.
3. Press and hold the power button for 5 seconds and then release it.
4. Press and hold power button again for 1.5 seconds and then release it.
Do I get it right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/84938/discussion-between-roderick-halim-and-buscar).

Comment: sorry, it is dinner time for me.....will be back, and yes try the power button stuff, a quick look shows your Mac been bussy

Comment: @Buscar웃 It doesn't work. The final step didn't occur on me.

Comment: Maybe some of the tips in this post will help to work around it: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/8518429

Answer (score 1):

The best way to shut down your Mac is to choose Shut Down from the Apple () menu.
Just as your Mac follows a startup process after it turns on, it follows a shutdown process before it turns off. That process includes automatically quitting all open apps and logging out of your macOS user account. 
If your Mac doesn't shut down, try [Force Quit](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201276) to close any apps that aren't responding. If that doesn't work, press and hold the power button until the Mac turns off.

Ok, here are the 3 power button options

1. Press the power button (briefly) to turn (off or on) the Mac or wake from sleep. Also called the normal method.
2. Press and hold the power button for 5 seconds or longer without lifting to **force** your Mac to turn off. Also called brutal method. Do not use frequently. It will not wake up after by any keyboard combination until you press the power button.
3. Press and hold power button for 1.5 seconds to get the turn off dialog. This dialog will ask if you want to restart, shutdown or put the Mac to sleep, this is the same as you would do with click under the Apple Icon (top left)

---

Other stuff...
You have a app called FOLX 5 Downloader that is preventing your Mac to Sleep. Quit that program, if it is still running, Open Activity Monitor find it and Quit it. You can also find it under its PID number `pid 6959`

[Here are some instructions how to deal with the T2 chip](https://eclecticlight.co/2018/07/17/firmware-the-smc-nvram-and-t2-chip-reset-and-maintain/).

Comment: Well, quit it and nothing change. By the way, my mac is on a T2 Chip. I guess it might be different from the prior one, especially that 3rd option. It never worked.

Comment: @RoderickHalim, just to confirm, when you press and HOLD the power button for 10 seconds, your Mac does not shut down ? you can still wake it up by pressing random keys (not the Power button).

Comment: Yeap, even a forced shutdown still unable to prevent this weird thing from happening. I think this is a bug from mojave maybe?

Comment: that is weird, it might be hardware (the SMC chip or in your case the T2 chip), but it might be some app that refuses to shut down (there must be a log in the console about that) look it up starting with the time stamp from the moment when you shut down). Did you do the SMC reset ?

Comment: Yeah, I have filed a bug report to Apple. This is a big issue since it happened to my partner in my office too. Three MBP having the same problem. No app preventing it, I have killed all app and force quit and make sure everything has stopped before I shut it down. I had done the SMC reset twice, still the same issue. I guess this is T2 chip issue since T2 handle all the low-level process which differ from the previous gen.

Comment: sorry could not help further, in you place I would have cut the power, either drained the battery or taken it out to kill the sucker. Maybe that would tech it a lesson to listen to me. :)

Comment: while waiting for Apple to respond, here is something for you to read about T2 reset. https://eclecticlight.co/2018/07/17/firmware-the-smc-nvram-and-t2-chip-reset-and-maintain/

Comment: Well, how I wish I could stab the battery lol Thanks a lot for your help mate. It's okay. Seems like no one has been able to find the solution too. Let's hope that Apple will respond to me.

Comment: I found some instructions how to deal with T2 https://eclecticlight.co/2018/07/17/firmware-the-smc-nvram-and-t2-chip-reset-and-maintain/